# MySQLI Connects, Doesn't INSERT/SELECT, No Errors

Tags: php, mysqli, xampp

I have a local instance of XAMPP running and everything works fine there. But when porting the application to HostGator I am able to connect to the database, but am unable to INSERT into it or SELECT.

I created a new user with all database rights, and attached the user to the database in question. Below is my code (with the credentials not showing here obviously):

dbconnect.php

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = '(myuser)';
$dbpass = '(my pass)';
$db     = '(mydb)';

$conn  = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser, $dbpass,$db);
```

helper.php (called from registration.php)

```
static function validateRegistration(){
    if (isset($_POST)) {
    //Gather And Sanitize User Input
    @$username      = sanitize($_POST["username"]);
    @$firstname     = sanitize($_POST["firstname"]);
    @$lastname      = sanitize($_POST["lastname"]);
    @$email         = sanitize($_POST["email"]);
    @$email         = (filter_var($email,  FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL));
    @$cellphone     = sanitize($_POST["cellphone"]);
    @$university    = sanitize($_POST["university"]);
    @$address       = sanitize($_POST["address"]);
    @$city          = sanitize($_POST["city"]);
    @$postcode      = sanitize($_POST["postcode"]);
    @$state         = sanitize($_POST["state"]);
    @$username      = sanitize($_POST["username"]);
    @$password      = sanitize($_POST["password"]);
    @$confirm       = sanitize($_POST["confirm"]);
    @$paymentmethod = sanitize($_POST["paymentmethod"]);
    @$PaymentID     = sanitize($_POST["PaymentID"]);

    //Collect errors, if any are present
    $errors = array();
            
    if (strlen($firstname) <= 1  || strlen($firstname) > 32){
        array_push($errors, 'First Name must be between 1 and 32 characters!');
    }else{
    }
    if (strlen($lastname) <= 1 || strlen($lastname) > 32){
        array_push($errors, 'Last Name must be between 1 and 32 characters!');
    }
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      array_push($errors, 'E-Mail Address does not appear to be valid!');
    }
    if (strlen($cellphone) <= 2 || strlen($cellphone) >= 32) {
      array_push($errors, 'Cell phone must be between 3 and 32 characters!');
    }
    if (strlen($address) <= 1 || strlen($address) >= 128) {
      array_push($errors, 'Address 1 must be between 3 and 128 characters!');
    }
    if (strlen($city) <= 1 || strlen($city) >= 128) {
      array_push($errors, 'City must be between 2 and 128 characters!');
    }
    if (strlen($postcode) <= 1 || strlen($postcode) >= 10) {
      array_push($errors, 'Postcode must be between 2 and 10 characters!');
    }
    if (strlen($password) <= 3 || strlen($password) >= 20) {
      array_push($errors, 'Password must be between 2 and 128 characters!');
    }
    if ($password != $confirm) {
      array_push($errors, 'Your passwords do not match!');
    }
}//END POST


//***********Check for available Username and Email***************//
include('dbconnect.php');
$registration = new RegistrationHelper();  
$sql = "SELECT Username FROM User WHERE Username = '" . $username . "'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    array_push($errors, 'Username is already taken');
}
$sql = "SELECT Email FROM User WHERE Email = '" . $email . "'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    array_push($errors, 'Email is already taken.');
}


if(count($errors) > 0){
    return $errors;
}else{
    include('dbconnect.php');
    //***************If we get this far, Register User - Will need admin approval***************
    $saltedPass = base64_encode($registration->salt . $password . $registration->salt); 
    $insertSQL = "INSERT INTO User (Username, FirstName, LastName, Email, Cell, Password, Active, PaymentGateway, PaymentGatewayID)
        Values ('" . $username . "', '" . $firstname . "', '" . $lastname . "', '" . $email . "', '" . $cellphone . "', '" . $saltedPass . "', 0, '" . $paymentmethod . "', '" . $PaymentID . "')";
    $conn->query($insertSQL);

    if ($conn->query($insertSQL) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
        $conn->close();

    }   

}


}//END validateRegistration()
```

The code runs in this function but fails on the 2 SELECT statements,

> $conn->query($sql);
>
> $conn->query($insertSQL);

And also does not pass this:

> if ($conn->query($insertSQL) === TRUE) {
>
> echo "Record created successfully";
>
> $conn->close();
>
> }

I've contacted HostGator to get their help and they don't have any idea. The user has all default (full) rights. The code hasn't changed and works final locally on XAMPP.

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur.**

Comment: Check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to find out why your select and insert statements would fail.

Comment: **No Errors because you dont look for them:)** Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to
the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)
If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: aynber, please kindly look at my code again. You will see I am calling a sanitize function which will prevent SQL injections :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently my local instance of MySQL was not case-sensitive, but on the HostGator instance, it was case-sensitive. By matching the case of the database tables, I was able resolve the issue.